# MPI_Comm_size Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, mpi, openmp

Mhm,Hello,everyone.I get these errors when running parallel program wiht MPI and OpenMP in Linux,

```
 [node65:03788] *** Process received signal ***
 [node65:03788] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
 [node65:03788] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
 [node65:03788] Failing at address: 0x44000098
 [node65:03788] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x2b663e446c00]
 [node65:03788] [ 1] /public/share/mpi/openmpi-   1.4.5//lib/libmpi.so.0(MPI_Comm_size+0x60) [0x2b663d694360]
 [node65:03788] [ 2] fdtd_3D_xyzPML_MPI_OpenMP(main+0xaa) [0x42479a]
 [node65:03788] [ 3] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4) [0x2b663e56f184]
 [node65:03788] [ 4] fdtd_3D_xyzPML_MPI_OpenMP(_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev+0x39) [0x405d79]
 [node65:03788] *** End of error message ***
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 mpirun noticed that process rank 2 with PID 3787 on node node65 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After I analysis the core files,I get following message:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 47310344057648 (LWP 26962)]
[New Thread 1075841344 (LWP 26966)]
[New Thread 1077942592 (LWP 26967)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 47310344057648 (LWP 26962)]
0x00002b074afb3360 in PMPI_Comm_size () from /public/share/mpi/openmpi-1.4.5//lib/libmpi.so.0
```

what causes these?  Thanks for your help

the code(test.cpp) is as follows,and you can have a try:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int nprocs = 1; //the number of processes
int myrank = 0; 
int provide;

MPI_Init_thread(&argc,&argv,MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED,&provide);
if (MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED != provide)  
{  
    printf ("%d != required %d", MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, provide);  
    return 0;  
}

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);  

int num_threads = 1;      //Openmp
omp_set_dynamic(1);
num_threads = 16;
omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);

#pragma omp parallel  
{  
    printf ("%d omp thread from %d mpi process\n", omp_get_thread_num(), myrank);  

}  
MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that is causing the segfault? You might need to compile your program with debugging enablead and run it in a debugger like `mpirun -np 2 xterm -e gdb -ex run parallel_program`.

Comment: Thanks for help,I don't know which code cause this,and I think it has something with MPI_Comm_size. And I am sorry that the source code is too long to show you. Addtional, the code can run in windows. After I change the run_environment into Linux,I use makefile to complie my code and there is nothing wrong, when run "mpirun -np 8 parallel_program",it has errors above.

Comment: Show us the relevant portions of your `main` function, including how you initialise MPI and how do you call `MPI_Comm_size`.

Comment: Mhm, you're code is working on my machine (Ubuntu 13.04, OpenMPI 1.4.5)...

Comment: Could you also show the corresponding OpenMP part?

Comment: Probably your OpenMP runtime initialises before the MPI library. You have to use `MPI_Init_thread` with thread level higher than `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`, which also requires Open MPI build that supports mutithreading (`opmi_info | grep -i thread` should show `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: yes`)

Comment: The OpenMP and MPI initalise are showed above...

Comment: can you give me your email, and I give the code to you...

Comment: Could you try this: http://pastebin.com/MgAyUJ5J - This is working for me. Compiled with `mpicc mpi.c -fopenmp -lmpi -I/usr/include/mpi/ -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/` (paths for Ubuntu 13.04), run as `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 mpirun -np 2 ./a.out`. What thread level do you get?

Comment: I use the gdb debugger, I get this:#0  0x00002ba52b27b360 in PMPI_Comm_size () from /public/share/mpi/openmpi-1.4.5//lib/libmpi.so.0
#1  0x00000000004247c5 in main ()

Comment: I set OMP_NUM_THREADS=16,and run as mpirun -np 8 parallel_program. @AlexanderVogt

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, there is no such thing as `end parallel` pragma in OpenMP for C/C++. The lexical scope of the `parallel` construct is the structured block immediately following the pragma line.

Comment: Sorry, I'm usually using Fortran ;-)

Comment: Hello，Hristo lliev. I use (ompi_info | grep -i thread),I get the following message:(**Thread support: posix (mpi: yes, progress: no)
   FT Checkpoint support: no  (checkpoint thread: no)**
). what should I do ? @HristoIliev

Comment: I have showed the code which can reproduce the error,I use the order  **mpiCC -openmp -limf -o mytest test.cpp** to compile it. And run like **mpirun -np 4 mytest**

Comment: Are you sure that `mpiCC` uses the same C++ compiler as the one used when the MPI library was built.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is probably not much, or even a bit of a lame answer, but I had this problem when mixing up different MPI installations (an OpenMPI and a MVAPICH2 to be precise).

Here are a few things to check

- against what version of MPI you linked

```
ldd <application> | grep -i mpi
    libmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib64/libmpi.so.1 (0x00007f90c03cc000)
```

- what version of MPI is dynamically loaded

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | tr : "\n" | grep -i mpi
/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib64
```

- whether you override this dynamic loading (this variable should be empty, unless you know what you're doing)

```
echo $LD_PRELOAD
```

If that's all OK, you need to check that each library you linked to and that relies on MPI was also linked with the same version. If no other library is linked to MPI, nothing should appear.

```
ldd <application> | sed "s/^\s*\(.*=> \)\?//;s/ (0x[0-9a-fA-F]*)$//" | xargs -L 1 ldd | grep -i mpi
```

If something suspect does show up, say `libmpich.so.3 => /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/MVAPICH2/1.8.1/lib/libmpich.so.3` for example, you should remove the -L 1 and replace grep with something to visualize (nothing ? or `less`, or `vim -` ...), then search for that suspect line.